# Product image not displayed in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON [image]

Answer (score 2):

**Reason 1:** You have wrong permissions on your /media/ folder

Solution: Change permissions to 777 recursively. You can do it using SSH via this command (execute it in Magento directory):

```
chmod -R 777 media/
```

**Reason 2:** Media folder is owned by another user. It can happen if you transfer your Magento store from one server to another

Solution: Change ownership of the /media/ folder:

```
chown -R {username}:{username} media/
```

**Reason 3:** Magento cannot resize images due low PHP memory limit. Magento resize images using GD library however if there is no sufficient amount of memory for such operation Magento will return a placeholder image

Solution: Increase your memory limit. You should open your .htaccess file and find this string:

```
php_value memory_limit 1024M
```

**Reason 4:** The GD library is not installed/configured

Solution: installed GD library on your server, you can check it using php info.

**Reason 5:** Wrong attribute scope for small_image, thumbnail, base_image. Sometimes Magento processes images incorrectly, if they have scope=Store View (especially in case of multi-store installation)

Solution: You should open your Magento backend > Catalog > Attributes > Manage attributes. After this you should find image, small_image & thumbnail attributes. Make sure that all these attributes have scope = Global.

**Reason 6:** Problem with safe mode

Solution: It is not recommended to disable safe mode, but if you tried all other solutions you might try to disable safe mode on your server